# How to count most consecutive occurrences of a value in a Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table `Attendance` in my database.

```
Date       | Present
------------------------
20/11/2013 |  Y
21/11/2013 |  Y
22/11/2013 |  N
23/11/2013 |  Y
24/11/2013 |  Y
25/11/2013 |  Y
26/11/2013 |  Y
27/11/2013 |  N
28/11/2013 |  Y
```

I want to count the most consecutive occurrence of a value `Y` or `N`.

For example in the above table `Y` occurs **2, 4 & 1 times**. So I want **4** as my result.
How to achieve this in SQL Server?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @astander- `SQL Server 2008`

Comment: How do you want to do this? In a StoredProc/UDF or just TSQL.

Comment: @DarrenS- `Stored Procedure` will we prefferable.

Comment: A pseudo code may be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

The difference between the consecutive date will remain constant

```
   Select max(Sequence)
  from 
  (
   select present ,count(*) as Sequence,
         min(date) as MinDt, max(date) as MaxDt
         from (
                select t.Present,t.Date,
                    dateadd(day,
                              -(row_number() over (partition by present order by date))
                               ,date 
                          ) as grp
              from Table1 t
            ) t
  group by present, grp
  )a
   where Present ='Y'
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38429/23)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT Date,Present,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date) RN
              FROM Table1)
     ,cte2 AS (SELECT Date,Present,RN,ct = 1 
               FROM cte
               WHERE RN = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT a.Date,a.Present,a.RN,ct = CASE WHEN a.Present = b.Present THEN ct + 1 ELSE 1 END
               FROM cte a
               JOIN cte2 b
                 ON a.RN = b.RN+1)
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM cte2
ORDER BY CT DESC
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5033f/16/0)

Note, the date's in the demo got altered due to the format you posted the dates in your question.