# Most number of consecutive login days

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have this table:

```
date        | has_login
------------------------
2015-01-01  | 1
2015-01-02  | 1
2015-01-03  | 0
2015-01-04  | 1
2015-01-05  | 1
2015-01-06  | 1
2015-01-07  | 0
2015-01-08  | 1
```

How do I get the most number of consecutive logins?
In this case, it should be **3**

Comment: check this..it might help..it talks of same question in detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472483/how-to-count-most-consecutive-occurrences-of-a-value-in-a-column-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select max(cons) as max_consecutives
from
(
    select @cons := case when has_login = 1 
                         then @cons + 1
                         else 1
                    end as cons
    from your_table
    cross join (select @cons := 0) c
    order by date
) tmp
```